# Convert type into python

Tags: c++, python, boost, types, export

I'm using boost python. I've exported some function which takes class `CL_DomElement` in arguments. Now, when I run app I have:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: CL_DomElement
```

So what about code. I've exported function which takes function-pointer in arguments. Here is the code:

```
typedef boost::function<boost::shared_ptr<Object> (CL_DomElement*, std::string& desc)> Parser;
void registerParser(std::string type, Parser p);

struct ParserProxy
{
    bp::object callable;

    ParserProxy(bp::object callable)
    : callable(callable)
    { }

    boost::shared_ptr<Object> operator()(CL_DomElement* elem, std::string& desc)
    {
        bp::object obj = callable(elem, desc);
        return bp::extract<boost::shared_ptr<Object> >(obj);
    }
};

void registerParserByProxy(std::string type, bp::object callable)
{
    registerParser(type, ParserProxy(callable));
}

// In some boost.python module
bp::def("RegisterParser", registerParserByProxy);
```

I register it this way (in python):

```
class TestObj(Object):
    @staticmethod
    def ParseTestObj(node, desc):
        print 'Parser is called!'
# Register parser
RegisterParser("testobj", TestObj.ParseTestObj)
```

It successfully registers, I check my map (register parser adds passed key→value into std::map) and everything is fine there (new value is added). Now I want to call passed pointer:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Object> TypesManager::parseObject(CL_DomElement* objectTag, const std::string &type, std::string &desc)
{
    return (getParser(type))(objectTag, desc);
}
```

`getParser` returns function-pointer from std::map with key `type`.

---

So, as I understand something wrong with passing class `CL_DomElement`. But I did in my module:

```
bp::class_<CL_DomElement>("CL_DomElement");
```

I think this shouldn't prevent such errors I described. So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Python call by reference : TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336942/boost-python-call-by-reference-typeerror-no-to-python-by-value-converter-fou)