# C++ Classes and Python Objects

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have two abstract C++ classes which I expose and derive in python. I am trying to extract those derived objects in C++ and call some method of one of the classes, passing an instance of the other class to the first. The classes are defined as such:

```
struct A {
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    virtual void a() = 0;
};

struct B {
    virtual void b(const A& a) = 0;
};
```

I expose them to Python using `boost::python`

```
namespace py = boost::python;

struct A_wrapper : A, py:wrapper<A> {
    void a() {
        this->getoverride("a")();
    }
};

struct B_wrapper : B, py::wrapper<B> {
    void b(const A& a) {
        this->get_override("b")(a);
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
    typedef std::vector<int> int_vec_t;

    py::class_<int_vec_t>("IntList")
        .def(py::vector_indexing_suite<int_vec_t>());

    py::class_<A_wrapper, boost::noncopyable>("A")
        .def_readwrite("numbers", &A::numbers)
        .def("a", py::pure_virtual(&A::a));

    py::class_<B_wrapper, boost::noncopyable>("B")
        .def("b", py::pure_virtual(&B::b));
}
```

My python classes just fill the numbers array with random numbers and `B::b` prints those numbers for debugging purposes.

I can import them and extract the two classes to `boost::shared_ptr`s without problems. Any python code in their initializer's is even called.

```
auto pyA = py::extract<boost::shared_ptr<A> >(/*py object containing derivation of A*/)();
auto pyB = py::extract<boost::shared_ptr<B> >(/*py object containing derivation of B*/)();
```

but when I try and call `pyB->b(*pyA)` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: A
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I call Python's derivation of `B::b` with an instance of `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is having to declare the abstract classes as `boost::noncopyable`. AS the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html) states:

> *`boost::noncopyable`* [sic] Suppresses automatic registration of to_python conversions which copy T instances. Required when  T has no publicly-accessible copy constructor.

So we can convert the python object to a C++ instance but not vica-versa which leads to the error in the question when we attempt to do just that.

The solution was in fact in the comments of the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336942/boost-python-call-by-reference-typeerror-no-to-python-by-value-converter-fo) question.

In the **wrapper** class, pass the object by reference instead of by value; so the class does not have to be converted to python. This leaves the wrapper looking like so:

```
struct B_wrapper : B, py::wrapper<B> {
    void b(const A& a) {
        this->get_override("b")(boost:ref(a));
    }
};
```