# Boost.python strange behavior Linux/Windows class convertors

Tags: python, c++, linux, windows, boost

I'm developing boost.python library for Linux/Windows. 
There are two modules. In the first module class A, in second module - class B. One of the method of B class returned instance of class A.
Under the linux it works as expected but under windows - not.

```
from modulea import A
from moduleb import B


b = B()
a = b.get_a_class()
```

There is an error
`TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class A`   under windows in last line.
But if I placed both of classes in one module it works.

Is there approach under windows to use two modules without such errors?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336942/boost-python-call-by-reference-typeerror-no-to-python-by-value-converter-fo

Comment: Nope, that link did not answer why it works under linux but windows - not. And why it works if both of those classes placed in one module =(

Comment: I tried out several boost versions: 1.54, 1.55, 1.57, 1.58, 1.61 but no luck

Comment: Does linking `modulea` and `moduleb` to the dynamic Boost.Python library resolve the problem?